# Azure Data Factory - How to move a Data Factory project from my account to the another account?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to move a Data Factory project from my account to the another account?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply migrate the data factory to a new resource group or subscription, the [move resource API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) is what you're looking for.